# How to print out the time in an EOS contract?

Tags: cleos

I expected to be able to print out the time in a contract but...

```
print(current_time());
```

didn't get compiled and I get the error "use of undeclared identifier 'current_time'"

Answer (score 1):

Time is treated in a special way inside the blockchain. The main reason for the limitation is that the blockchain data needs to be consistent and reproducible so playback of the blockchain reaches the same state.

This should work:

```
print(now());
```

Comment: Ami, when I compile im getting an error
error: use of undeclared identifier 'now'; did you mean 'new'? print(now());

Comment: What version are you using for the eosio.cdt?

Comment: if i run `cleos version client` i get Build version: 448287d5

Comment: What version of the eosio.cdt? Try this: >> eosio-cpp --version

Comment: `eosio-cpp --version` eosio-cpp version 1.6.1 but i did just run `brew upgrade eosio`

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. When I compile, I et no such errors. Try posting the minimal contract code with just the now() function or the current_time() which gives you the error.

Comment: What headers are you including? `current_time()` should work with CDT 1.6

Answer (score 1):

In more recent version of eosio.cdt, now(), which used to return the seconds since the beginning of the unix epoch, has been removed.

The new way of doing this would be:

```
#include <eosio/system.hpp>

print(current_time_point().sec_since_epoch());
```